# Android, Volley,SQL Only one Record being displayed?

Tags: java, php, android, sql, listview

so after much trouble shooting i have finally gotten my list view working.

Essentially my table has 3 records which should match id 1. I want these to be displayed in my android listview, only 1 is displayed. I assume my php is correct as when i enter 
myurl://retreiveData.php?id=1

All 3 records are displayed, how ever the android application only displays 1

I will post my php below, and the extract from the java which loops through the json data

```
 <?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
   $id  = $_GET['id'];
   require_once('dbConnect.php');
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Exercises WHERE id='".$id."'";
   $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
   $result = array();
   array_push($result,array(
   "muscle group"=>$res['muscle group'],
   "exercise"=>$res['exercise'],
  )
  );
   echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
  }
   mysqli_close($con);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the line `$result = array();` above your `while` loop in PHP.

On every iteration you are creating a new object. On browser you are able to see because you print the value in each iteration but at the end of the `while` loop, it will only have the last value. You can test it by echoing the value of `$result` after the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense, also worth noting i had  "echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));". With in the while loop, moving it outside of it aswell as moving the array line above the loop fixed this. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help. You can accept the answer as correct, if it solved your problem. It will be helpful for future visitors.